# Can't open PID file on Cent OS 7 for Apache status

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, systemd

Found following on systemctl status httpd.service on Cent OS 7. 
Apache 2.4.41 is compiled and installed. There is not such message on Cent OS 6.

> systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/httpd.pid (yet?) after start:
>   No such file or directory

Even though this showing in status server start and stop are working fine.

Here is service file:

```
cat /run/systemd/generator.late/httpd.service
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8) 
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd 
Description=LSB: start and stop Apache HTTP Server 
Before=shutdown.target 
After=remote-fs.target 
After=network-online.target 
After=nss-lookup.target 
After=distcache.service 
Wants=network-online.target 
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min 
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no 
KillMode=process 
GuessMainPID=no 
RemainAfterExit=no 
PIDFile=/var/run/httpd.pid 
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start 
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd stop 
ExecReload=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd reload


/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "/var/run/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>
```

Any idea?

Comment: The creation of the pid file is configured in the service itself (in this case apache), not systemd.

Comment: CentOS 6 doesn't use `systemd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you compiled and installed Apache from source, and it hasn't been configured properly.

If the file `/var/run/httpd.pid` does not exist, you need to correct it. On my CentOS 7 system with the included version of Apache, it is found at `/run/httpd/httpd.pid`

You can change the path in the unit file. However, I would recommend installing Apache from a package repository if you want to run a newer version than what is included with CentOS, or you will run into many issues like this that you will have to troubleshoot.

When you compile and install software yourself, you will have to support it yourself.

Comment: We have compiled and installed latest 2.4.41. The PID file in created in the same path but not sure why this warning shows on status check. When I comment the PIDFile=/var/run/httpd.pid entry from service file, the warning is not showing. In both case, there is PID file in the same path.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in your Apache config file `PidFile` not exist or not set according your `.service` file. You should set it to `PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid` to remove this error, or change your `.service` file to set proper path to existing Apache pid file.

Answer (score 0):

If you read this: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=

it says:

> PIDFile=

> Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for services where Type= is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below /run/. If a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with /run/.

Because the path to PID file that you mention in httpd.service is relative to /run then you shouldn't add /run to your PID file path.

Because you have installed Apache from source then you get that error as in contrast to your Linux distro, you have to do all the settings by hand.

Do the followings:

1. Open your httpd.conf file and set the PID file to a file in /run:

   ```
   PidFile "/run/httpd.pid"
   ```
2. Open your httpd.service (it is in /etc/systemd/system/) and under [Service] mention the PID filename that systemd should find:

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
   ExecStop=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl graceful-stop
   ExecReload=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl graceful
   # systemd will add /run to your relative path.
   #  therefore, your httpd PID file in /run/httpd.pid can be found
   PIDFile=httpd.pid
   PrivateTmp=true
   LimitNOFILE=infinity
   ```

The above two steps will eliminate this error:
... httpd-latest.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/httpd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory